# Window.open() to trigger phone SMS/Call/Email app not working in Chrome on Android on Page Load - Using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs

This is my code snippet.

```
else if (item.title === 'Text') {
             try {
                     window.open(`sms:${item.link}`,'_self')
             } catch (error) {
                 console.log(error)
             }
```

When this function is executed on a page load, it does not automatically trigger the SMS app. This issue only occurs on Chrome Android browser. Works for Safari, Mozilla, and Opera. When executed as an onClick, it works perfectly on all browsers, including Chrome on Android. Only facing an issue on page load in Chrome.

The framework I am using is React JS.

Comment: Running this on iOS 15.2.1, I get a popup asking me to open Messages. Is this expected?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes! On iOS, it seems to work perfectly on all browsers. But on Chrome in Android, it doesn't ask me to open Messages/Call/Email app.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work.
For some strange reason Andriod doesn't allow dynamically created links for `SMS:` even if the output string makes a correct link!
For example if I copy the output of my function that creates an SMS link as a literal text in an anchor (like `<a href="sms://1234/?body=body">Click for SMS</a>`) or even if I do `window.open("sms://1234/?body=body")` (provided that the link is correctly formed) it works, but very strangely if I replace it with the output of a function it won't!!
I wasted half of my day to find a way around it so far without any luck!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).